# How to make dynamic menu with categories

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, menu, categories

I have a website and I want to add automatically categories to my menu. I mean when I create new category it should appear in my menu. How I can make it?

```
  <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'header', 'container' => '' ) ); ?>

Home | Categories | Contact
          category1
          category2
          category3
```

Comment: How are you 'creating new categories' now?

Comment: Store all category names in a DB table, along with their respective `href` values. Depending on the site, there will be a directory structure that is predictable (pages are always served using similar routes), you will need to recognize this directory structure and build a simple CMS around it.

Comment: I make new category in wordpress admin

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Create the categories and publish posts in those categories. Then create your menu.

From the sidebar nav on the left in *wordpress>>appearance>>menus* scroll down and add categories to your menu.

Secondary and third child menus have been a standard feature in the several last recent releases of WP.

Option 2: If for some reason you don't have this feature on your install/setup, add direct urls and add labels to the menu.

Happy publishing.